# What is the syntax for duplicating a SQL statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am very new to SQL and I wanted to see if anyone could assist me with the syntax for duplicating a basic SQL percentile statement. Here is the code I am trying to duplicate:

```
SELECT Max(CompData.Salary) AS 50th
FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Salary FROM CompData ORDER BY Salary)  AS [%$##@_Alias];
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT Max(CompData.Salary) AS 50th
FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Salary FROM CompData ORDER BY Salary)  AS [%$##@_Alias],
FROM (SELECT TOP 60 PERCENT Salary FROM CompData ORDER BY Salary)  AS [%$##@_Alias];
```

I get Syntax error FROM clause
How do I duplicate this (without a syntax error) for the 60th percentile for instance?

Thanks so much!

Comment: And the output should be?

Comment: The output should be the 50th and 60th percentiles based on a column of salaries.

Comment: A single SELECT statement can only have one FROM clause.   Instead of a simple English description of your desired output, adding a formatted example of your desired output would be more helpful.

Comment: How would it look if I wanted to use two separate SELECT statements?

Comment: Depends, how many rows should be in the result?  how many columns?   How will the user be able to tell which is the 50th and which is the 60th?

Comment: One column for each result. So two in this case. One column would be titled 50th and the other 60th with the value in a row beneath each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the second `from`.  A SQL `SELECT` has only one `FROM` clause (additional `from` clauses would be in subqueries).

You do *not* want to do what you are attempting.  The problem is that the `,` does a Cartesian product.  So, if your table has 1,000 rows, then your intermediate result would have 500*600 = 300,000 rows -- and a big performance hit.

You can use `percentile_disc()` or `precentile_cont()` for this purpose.  But, for your query, you simply want to do the aggregation *before* the join:

```
SELECT q50.val, q60.val
FROM (SELECT Max(CompData.Salary) AS val
      FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Salary FROM CompData ORDER BY Salary) t
     ) q50 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT Max(CompData.Salary) AS val
      FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Salary FROM CompData ORDER BY Salary) t
     ) q60;
```

There are other methods of doing this calculation, but this seems like the approach you are using in your question.

EDIT:

Your question is tagged *SQL SERVER* not *MS ACCESS*.  The tags are important.  MS Access syntax is more like:

```
SELECT q50.val, q60.val
FROM (SELECT Max(CompData.Salary) AS val
      FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Salary FROM CompData ORDER BY Salary) as t
     ) as q50,
     (SELECT Max(CompData.Salary) AS val
      FROM (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Salary FROM CompData ORDER BY Salary) as t
     ) as q60;
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting this error "Syntax error in FROM clause" when I attempt to save. I am trying this script in an Access database. I'm not sure if that's relevant. Any ideas?